# How many cases for this case?(Balls and boxes)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

$Q)$ There are $12$ balls and same two boxes. Among the $12$ balls, $6$ balls are same but the rest of the $6$ are different respectively. (I.e. There are $7$ types of the $12$ balls.) How many cases the balls put into the two boxes?
(Here the case of the empty box allowed.)

$(sol)$ Let the balls $a,a,a,a,a,a,1,2,3,4,5,6$

$(1)$ The "$a$" balls : there are $4$ cases because of the below

- Each boxes and the balls are indistinguishable respectively. So $ 0+6 = 1+5 = 2+4= 3 +3$

$(2)$ The "$1$ to $6$" balls : $S(6,1) + S(6,2) = 32$ cases (Here the $S(n,k)$ is the $2$nd stirring number)

So my answer is $4\times 32 = 128$

Are my answer and solution right?

Comment: You need to distinguish the case in which the indistinguishable balls are split equally. In that case the symmetry matters.  In the other cases the two boxes are no longer the same so the symmetry is broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed $4$ ways to distribute the indistinguishable balls.  $3$ of those suffice to distinguish the two boxes, the $(3,3)$ distribution does not.

For each of the $3$ distributions other than $(3,3)$, we have $2^6=64$ ways to distribute the distinct balls.  That gives us $3\times 64=192$ distributions.

For the $(3,3)$ case we do indeed have $2^5=32$ ways to distribute the distinct balls, as we must divide by $2$ to account for the symmetry.

Thus the answer is $192+32=224$.

Answer (score 2):

There are different approaches to this problem. I prefer the following one.

First make the boxes distinguishable. Attach a sticks "1" and "2" to these boxes. And calculate number of possibilities in this case.

There are now 7 possibilities to arrange "a" balls: 0 + 6; 1 + 6; ... ; 6 + 0.
And there are 2^6 = 64 possibilities to arrange "1", ... "6" balls.
Total number of possibilities is 7 * 64.

Note, that all the possibilities can be arranged to pairs: for any arrangement of balls by boxes you can move all the balls from box "1" into box "2" and vice versa - you will get a different arrangement. And these cases become the same case if you remove the sticks from boxes.

That means that the number of cases in the original problem is exactly 1/2 of the number of cases when boxes are different.

And the final answer would be 7 * 64 / 2 = 224.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig (facepalm) 2 ** 6 = 64, not 32. Thank you.